# Common footer with multiple links

Tags: javascript, html, code-reuse

I want to add a common footer for all my html pages, but the footer has links to different pages in different folders, how can I do this?
The problem is, I can write the footer with respect to one page, where the links point to, but what about other pages?
I want a reusable footer with access to all the correct folder locations in each page I call the footer in.

I tried using a js page for the footer and bringing all the html pages under one main folder, but that isnt the right way to do it.
Any alternate solutions?

Comment: Please show what you've attempted, but I think you need to use your links with respect to the web root.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: [jquery](https://jquery.com/)

Comment: @mykaf 
let id = path.match(/([^\/]*)\/*$/)[1];
    console.log(id);
    const dataInd = footer_link.data.findIndex((ele) => ele.key === id);
I have used this to extract the folder location so I can pass it as a key and have created a json with respective links.

Answer (score -1):

The way I usually do this is to create an empty placeholder div for the footer (and header, normally), and use a header-footer.js file to write code into those divs.  For large nav structures, I build the nav as a data structure stored in a variable, usually via nested objects, then iterate through that with a function that generates the HTML and places it into the placeholder div.

You can check out my implementation at https://github.com/sdcervi/Reference if you want to see the specifics.